# Why are my variables giving a different value when they are printed outside of the class I set them in?

Tags: c++, variables, integer, output, text-based

I am making fairly new to C++ and I am using it to make a text based game for a school project. However during the first section of the game the player answers questions by entering the number shown beside the answer they choose. However when I tested the variables the input going to using **std::cout** they return different values depending on where they are outputted. If I outputted them in the class I am using to set them (**Introduction**) the they return the correct value such as 1 or 3 etc. However when I output them in any file other than **Introduction.cpp**, the value displayed is -858993460 for all of the values. I get the same result from **Main.cpp** when I call them in my **main** function and if I call them from another function in a different class to **Introduction**.

This is an example of some of the code used to get input from the user:

```
void Introduction::CharacterCreation()
{
    Universal universal;

    std::fstream creation("Introduction_CharacterCreation.txt");
    universal.line = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < universal.line; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            std::getline(creation, universal.displayText);
            std::cout << universal.displayText << std::endl;
        }
        if (i == 4)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cin >> universal.gender;

            while (universal.gender <= 0 || universal.gender >= 3)
            {
                std::cout << "Please make a valid choice" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> universal.gender;
            }
        }
    }
// Code cut out here
}
```

The **gender** variable is an **int** declared in the **Universal** class, and the user is prompted to enter 1 for male or 2 for female by text pulled from a separate file. If the input is not 1 or 2 then a while loop forces the player to keep re-answering the question until they enter 1 or 2. The **line** variable is also an **int** however that is used for the **for** loops to ensure the right lines are read by the program.

To output the **gender** variable this is the code I use:

```
std::cout << gender << std::endl;
```

There is no **universal.** as it is being called within the **Universal** class itself.

This has confused me massively and I can't get my head around what is causing the problem. Any help or explanation would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: The `universal` variable in that function gets destroyed after this function runs. Since you're not showing how you're getting it out of there, we can't guess exactly what you're doing wrong - possibly just manipulating a completely unrelated variable in the code "outside".

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use `universal` after it has gone out of scope (which is why you are seeing values like -858993460). You are creating it on the stack and so its scope is local to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you're declaring a `Universal` object in your `CharacterCreation()` method. When this function exits since the **scope** of the `universal` variable was local so the entire object is destroyed.

Whatever you are outputting is just uninitialized **garbage**. It could really be any number depending on what system is compiling / running the program. To test this right after you input the gender, while still inside the function, try running

`std::cout << universal.gender << std::endl;`

This should output just fine.

There are a lot of ways you can go about fixing this. Since you didn't post where you call this method or your `Universal` class I can't say for sure. But I can speculate one such solution which is to declare the `Universal` object outside the method and then pass it in as a parameter:

```
Universal universal = Universal();
Introduction::CharacterCreation(universal);
std::cout << universal.gender << std::endl;
```

And just declare your function header to accept a `Universal` object:

```
void Introduction::CharacterCreation(Universal & universal)
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: I just took it out, probably a little more in-depth than he needs! Also since it's a text based program I'd be willing to guess it's probably not *that* heavy.